# NativeScript Error - Node Identifier did not pass test 'isStatement'

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to run my app using

```
tns run android
```

The app was created using command

```
tns create mayApp
```

and i did not updated the project yet and facing the below error

> ERROR in : Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Unexpected node.
>   Verbose Debug Information: Node Identifier did not pass test
>   'isStatement'.

**env info**

OS macOS 10.14.3 
 node v11.0.0 n
 pm 6.4.1 
 tns 5.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround V5:

1. Change "useLegacyWorkflow" to true on your nsconfig.json
2. Use --bundle option. `tns run android --bundle`

or migrate to V6:

1. `tns migrate`
2. `tns update`
3. `./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs`
4. Optional: (Needs to be done on a clean git branch)

   `ng update @angualar/cli @angular/core`

Answer (score 3):

See if you have an environment variable **'NODE_ENV'** being set to **development** somewhere and remove it. This seems to switch the TypeScript compilation to Debug mode which in some cases crashes with the above error.